# How to find an exact word in a string in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of strings in the following format:

target:

```
'TLS 1.2 x67 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DH 2048 AES128 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256'

'TLS 1 x67 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DH 2048 AES128 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256'

'TLS 1.1 x67 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DH 2048 AES128 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256'
```

I want to know if only the exact match of 'TLS 1' (and not TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2) exist in a line.

I have tried solutions in similar post as following:

```
#returns all the lines including TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2 ...    
lines = []    
    for i in target:
        if re.match(r'\bTLS 1\b', i):
            lines.append(i)
```

also tried:

```
#returns nothing  
lines = []    
    for i in target:
        if re.match(r'^TLS 1$', i):
            lines.append(i)
```

and many other variations with search or findall etc. How can I only grab the lines with exact and only exact match of a given word?

Comment: Use `r'\bTLS 1\s'` or `r'\bTLS 1(?!\S)'` for a more generic case to match `TLS 1` followed with whitespace or end of string. Or `\bTLS 1(?!\.?\d)` to match only if not followed with a digit or `.` + digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider the following approaches.

`TLS` as a whole word should have a word boundary right in front of it, so that part is covered in your pattern.

If there must be a whitespace right after `1`, or end of string, it is more efficient to use a negative lookahead `(?!\S)`: `r'\bTLS 1(?!\S)'`. Well, you may also use `r'\bTLS 1(?:\s|$)'`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fPASIb/2).

If you just want to ensure there is no digit or a fractional part after `1` use

```
r'\bTLS 1(?!\.?\d)'
```

This will match `TLS 1` that has no `.` or `.` + digit after it. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fPASIb/3).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/ypQqwm):

```
import re
target = ['TLS 1.2 x67 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DH 2048 AES128 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256', 'TLS 1 x67 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DH 2048 AES128 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256', 
'TLS 1.1 x67 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DH 2048 AES128 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256']
lines=[]
for i in target:
    if re.match(r'\bTLS 1(?!\.?\d)', i):
        lines.append(i)
print(lines)
```

Output:

```
['TLS 1 x67 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DH 2048 AES128 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256']
```

Answer (score 2):

Wiktor commented before I posted this (not surprising), but the marker for an exact match in this case is actually a *space* following `TLS 1`.  A word boundary is not specific enough, because that would also pick up things like `TLS 1.1`, which you don't want.  So try this version:

```
#returns all the lines including TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2 ...    
lines = []    
    for i in target:
        if re.match(r'\bTLS 1\s', i):
            lines.append(i)
```

If the `TLS` text could possibly be the very last thing in a line, then we can try using this:

```
re.match(r'\bTLS 1(?=(\s|$))', i)
```